# How to create and add basic page in windows phone 7/8 in run-time in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am a new learner and i have searched this for a long time , that can we add different types of pages in run-time using c# in windows phone 7 or windows phone 8.

As we manually define no of pages while creating an application by going to project and adding a page which finally gives us a .XAML page , but i want to achieve it using run-time not by manually adding .

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?

Well you can just write

```
 var page = new PhoneApplicationPage();
```

and do everything in C# of course.